# LARAVEL: "vagrant provision" command drops database and tables

Tags: laravel-5, vagrant, homestead

Here is what I do;

Lets say I have already project and running okay with db

Adding new Laravel project as a second.

Adding site name to Homestead.yaml (same as first project)

**Homestead.yaml**

```
sites:
    - map: first.app
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/first/public
    - map: second.app
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/second/public
```

Update hosts file

**hosts**

```
127.0.0.1   first.app
127.0.0.1   second.app
```

http://first.app:8000 running okay

http://second.app:8000 goes to first.app

To update homestead I use following command under homestead direction.Then second.app website working okay.

```
vagrant provision
```

But I am loosing all my tables in db which is connected to first.app

**Note:vagrant halt/up didn't help to make work for the second.app**

Is there any way to update homestead without using "vagrant provision" ?

Comment: What's your Vagrantfile look like? Do you have a provisioner block for each app?

Comment: When I run "vagrant provision" command it does the job.I got only one ID for VM.I haven't touched  Vagrantfile to make it run!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution:

Edit (with Sublime Text Shift+cmd+P search for create-mysql.sh)

**create-mysql.sh**

**From**

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

DB=$1;

mysql -uhomestead -psecret -e "DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS \`$DB\`";
mysql -uhomestead -psecret -e "CREATE DATABASE \`$DB\` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci";
```

**To**

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

DB=$1;
mysql -uhomestead -psecret -e "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS \`$DB\` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci";
```

**Now `vagrant provision` run as expected and I can view new added websites!**

Answer (score 1):

Add your-url.app to etc/hosts

ssh into homestead

serve your-url.app /home/vagrant/Code/YourUrlApp/public 80

Bingo, no need to provision from homestead, after creating first site ;)